# error: ELF header smaller than expected

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, boot

So I had updated ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and while computer was rebooting I turned it down and automaticly this showed:

```
error : ELF header smaller than expected .
Grub rescue>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ELF header smaller than expected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401105/elf-header-smaller-than-expected)

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a **LiveCD** of your distribution, select the Advanced mode, then choose Recovery mode (you have to enter the **shell**). After you do this, and assuming that your bootloader is installed on **/dev/sda**, run this shell supercommand:

```
update-grub && grub-install /dev/sda && telinit 6
```

Your computer will be restarted. Remove the LiveCD from the drive, so your computer can boot its operating system in "normal" mode.